# Is $\bigcap_{i\in I}(M_i/N)=\bigl(\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\bigr)/N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, quotient-spaces

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, $N$ a submodule of $M$ and $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ a family of submodules of $M$ such that $N\subseteq M_i$ for all $i\in I$. Is this true that $\bigcap_{i\in I}(M_i/N)=\bigl(\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\bigr)/N$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: @Bernard Even if $I$ be an infinite set?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the cardinality if the index set. Just think of what are denoted on both sides of the equality: on the left, a congruence class which can be written as some $x_i+N$ for each $i$, and on the right, an element which can be written as $x+N$ for some $x$ belonging to all the $M_i$s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the canonical map $\pi\colon M\to M/N$; then
$$
\pi^{-1}\bigl(\bigcap_i(M_i/N)\bigr)=\bigcap_i M_i
$$
Since also
$$
\pi^{-1}\bigl(\bigl(\bigcap_i M_i\bigr)/N)\bigr)=\bigcap_i M_i
$$
you can easily end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can show inclusion both ways as follows:

Let $m\in M$ and $mN\in M/N$ be a coset.

If $mN\in \bigcap_{i\in I}(M_i/N)$ then $\forall n\in N:m+n\in M_i\implies m=m+0\in M_i$, so 
$$m\in \bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\implies mN\in\bigl(\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\bigr)/N$$

Conversely, if $mN\in \bigl(\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\bigr)/N$ then

$$m\in\bigcap_{i\in I}M_i\implies mN\in\bigcap_{i\in I}(M_i/N)$$

Comment: Thanks. It is correct. But i think it is better (and perhaps should) to use $m+N$ instead of $mN$. Thanks again.